# The image dissapears when i change it's properties too fast

Tags: jquery, css, image

There is full code of my page so you can see it on your own:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style type = "text/css">
        #img1 {
            opacity: 1;
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #img2 {
            opacity: 1;
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #cont {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 880px;
            height: 360px;
            border: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            background-color: red;
            z-index: 100;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var check = 0;
            var ended = 1;
            var ended2 = 1;
            $("#img2").mouseenter(function()
            {
                if (check == 0 && ended == 1)
                {
                    ended = 0;
                    $("#img2").fadeOut(500, function()
                    {
                        $("#img2").css({"z-index":"2"});
                        $("#img1").css({"z-index":"3"});
                        ended = 1;
                    }).fadeIn(1);
                    check = 1;
                }
            });
            $("#cont").mouseleave(function()
            {
                check = 0;
                if (ended2 == 1)
                {
                    ended2 = 0;
                    $("#img1").fadeOut(500, function()
                    {
                        $("#img2").css({"z-index":"4"});
                        $("#img1").css({"z-index":"1"});
                        ended2 = 1;
                    }).fadeIn(1);
                }   
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id = "cont">
    <img src = "http://s16.postimg.org/egzrkpa1h/img1.jpg" id = "img1">
    <img src = "http://s23.postimg.org/kzurc5h63/img2.jpg" id = "img2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code works simply: when mouse focuses on picture, it "change colors", when leaves the red div - it returns to the previous state. 
The problem is: when i move mouse into in the picture's area before the script is ended (before 500ms of starting animation), both of the pictures dissapear for a moment. I have added the condition with variables ended and ended2 - and i don't know why they don't work.. I've spended all night searching for the mistake and i didn't find anything, so please help me :)

Comment: Try to stop animation on another image using http://api.jquery.com/stop/ like this `$("#img2").stop(true, true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the two pictures become transparent at the same time, so you will see the background. Try applying transparency only to the top image, then you don't have to change their orders with z-index or anything, but...

You don't need javascript to do that. Add a hover state via css and you will get the same result. Try removing all of your javascript and just add this to your css:

```
#img2:hover {opacity:0;} 
#img2 {transition: opacity 0.5s;}
```

If you really want to use jQuery, try hover, where the first parameter is "on mouse over", and second "on mouse leave":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var topImage = $("#img2");
    topImage.hover(
        function(){
            topImage.stop().animate({opacity:0});
        },
        function(){
            topImage.stop().animate({opacity:1});         
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Ech.. It works :) I've tried this css of course (on the beggining) but there was some problem with it - probably i've done some mistake - and i switched to jQuery.
Anyway - thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**SCRIPT:**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var check = 0;
        var ended = 1;
        var ended2 = 1;
        $("#img2").mouseenter(function()
        {
            if (check == 0 && ended == 1)
            {
                ended = 0;
                $("#img2").stop(true,true).fadeOut(500, function()
                {
                    $("#img2").css({"z-index":"2"});
                    $("#img1").css({"z-index":"3"});
                    ended = 1;
                }).stop(true,true).fadeIn(1);
                check = 1;
            }
        });
        $("#cont").mouseleave(function()
        {
            check = 0;
            if (ended2 == 1)
            {
                ended2 = 0;
                $("#img1").stop(true,true).fadeOut(500, function()
                {
                    $("#img2").css({"z-index":"4"});
                    $("#img1").css({"z-index":"1"});
                    ended2 = 1;
                }).stop(true,true).fadeIn(1);
            }   
        });
    });
```